# GET STIX data from TAXII server based on indicators (IP and Hash)

Tags: python, xml, security

I am working on a project where I need to retrieve the STIX data from TAXII server(HailaTaxii in my case) and parse the data for indicators and TTP's.

### I am facing the below problem.

1) Unable to retrieve the STIX data from TAXII server based on specific indicators like IP/Hash. Getting the following error while querying using ***query_client*** of libtaxii.

> query_client --value 10.0.0.0 --host hailataxii.com --path /taxii-data
>
> Request:
>
> Message Type: Poll_Request Message ID: 7254973653021250806
>   Collection Name: default   Excl. Begin TS Label: None   Incl. End TS
>   Label: None   === Poll_Parameters ===
>       === Query ===
>         Query Format: urn:taxii.mitre.org:query:default:1.0
>         Targeting Expression ID: urn:stix.mitre.org:xml:1.1.1
>       === Criteria ===
>         Operator: AND
>         === Criterion ===
>           Negate: False
>           Target: **/@id
>           === Test ==
>             Capability ID: urn:taxii.mitre.org:query:capability:core-1
>             Relationship: equals
>             Parameter: match_type = case_insensitive_string
>             Parameter: value = 10.0.0.0
>       Response type: FULL
>
> Response:
>
> ---
>
> Message Type: Status_Message Message ID: 50428; In Response To: 0
>   Status Type: BAD_MESSAGE Message: exception while parsing received
>   message ("A deserializer for the query format
>   'urn:taxii.mitre.org:query:default:1.0' is not registered.")
>
> ---

I am using ***libtaxii version (1.1.110)***

Thanks

Comment: This may be related to [issue #13](https://github.com/TAXIIProject/java-taxii/issues/13) of the Java client